# Saving some entries and a matrix field settings takes a very long time

Tags: entries, matrix

I have some issues with saving fields and entries in Craft. For some reason, some entries, and a Matrix field I have, take approx. 1 to 2 minutes to save. There are then errors in my server log.

Initially I thought it was due to using Assets fields, as when I deleted those, the matrix field saved OK, and the entry. I recreated a field using Assets and when added some images to an entry, the issue came back.

It still saves, just takes 1 to 2 minutes.

For info, this is a site I copied from another site, then changed it's database, any paths/domains in config, then deleted a bunch of entries and assets we don't need on the new site, then the issue started to happen.

Here is the error in the server log. Online it says increate the timeout, but thats not a solution, it should not be taking this long in the first place.

```
[Fri Jul 08 16:00:24.139890 2016] [fcgid:warn] [pid 32671] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client xx.xx.xx.xx:50434] mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function, referer: http://mydomain.co.uk/admin/entries/homepage/2-homepage
```

**Update**: I have since copied the site again and gone through the same process as above, and its working OK now. So not urgent for me, but will leave this issue here nevertheless as its a serious issue of course.

Comment: Any chance you've got gzip output compression enabled on your site either at the PHP or Apache level?

Comment: Yes we alway have gzip enabled. But another site on same server with same fields is ok.

Comment: I ask because we've seen something that sound similar on a few random servers that have gzip compression enabled and a Craft task is running that triggers automatically. You can try either disabling gzip and/or setting https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#runTasksAutomatically to false and setting up a cron job to trigger tasks to see if that helps.

Comment: The site was a copy of another site, with entries and images deleted. I have now re-copied the original site again, deleted the entries and images like before, and its working fine. I have no idea why this would have happened the first time.

Comment: Yeah, that's weird.  Maybe just some odd environmental issue. Probably worth adding your update as an actual answer to the question, though.