# Attaching a file to a Matrix field and then saving the entry takes up to 2 minutes

Tags: entries, matrix

I have an issue with attaching a file to a Matrix field and then saving the entry takes up to 2 minutes. If I open up another tab with the Craft CMS admin interface I can see that Craft is performing the task: "Delete Stale Template Caches"

This does not happen in DevMode.

I have read: https://craftcms.com/support/stuck-tasks but none of our templates are using the {% cache %} tag. Also there is nothing logged in: craft/storage/runtime/logs/phperrors.log I also tried clearing the caches to no avail.

I have also found:
[Saving some entries and a matrix field settings takes a very long time](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/15850/saving-some-entries-and-a-matrix-field-settings-takes-a-very-long-time)
but this does not provide any real answers.

The server is running PHP 7.0.20 and running Nginx as a reverse proxy in front of Apache via ServerPilot.

Comment: Does it happen when you save the same Matrix field without attaching a file?  How big is the file and what type of file is it?

Comment: This does not happen when adding a matrix field without a file attached. Further testing suggest that it only happens with PDF files. This was a 27Kb .pdf file. With a larger .png it does not happen. Both files were already uploaded to assets, so they where just attached to the entry.

Comment: Hrm... all PDF files or just that one? Any chance you've got something like mod_security or Suhosin installed on that box?

Comment: This happens with any PDF files. Mod_Security or Sushosin are not installed.

Comment: Are you using http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php or http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php on your server?  If it's the former, can you try installing the later? Craft will automatically use it by default if it is installed.

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for looking at this. Unfortunately, still no luck, I installed and verified ImageMagick as per: https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-install-the-php-imagemagick-extension.html but the issue still happens.

Comment: Hi Brad, just an update, this seems to be happening with .xlsx (MS Excel) files. Could it be some security scanning issue, I'm think xss filtering on EE had simular issues.

Comment: Hrm... seems unlikely?  Craft does some cleansing of image files and SVG files, but pretty much leaves all of the other ones alone.  Super weird, though.

Comment: Ok, I think I have found the issue. We were using a Craft plugin called SearchPlus to index the entries on Angolia, not indexing this type of entry anymore solved the issue. I will look further into why this was happening and report back any findings. Thanks for the help Brad.

Comment: Ahh... nice find.  Be sure and add an answer once you get to the bottom of it... might save someone a headache in the future.